# Formulario com validação em JS

Tags: javascript, front-end

boa noite pessoal, estou tentando criar um formulário que que dê um callback de "campo obrigatorio" quando o campo estiver vazio, pra isso utilizei o innerHTML pra adicionar texto. O problema é o seguinte, o innerHTML não esta repetindo embaixo de todos campos do formulario, voces poderiam me ajudar pra entender onde estou errando? Estou tentando não usar nenhum plugin nem framework pois estou aprendendo o FrontEnd, então quero ir por partes. Vou inserir só a parte do JS e se precisarem do restante do codigo eu  deixo o link do github também

[Código completo no GitHub](https://github.com/MiguelCavilha/Quest-HTML-CSS-Js-Intermedi-rio/blob/main/src/JS/index.js)

```js
const inputsFormulario = document.querySelectorAll(".input")

const confirmarBotao = document.querySelector("button")
const form = document.getElementById("form")

confirmarBotao.addEventListener("click", () =>{

    form.addEventListener("submit", (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();


    })

    inputsFormulario.forEach((input) => {

        const campoOb =
            input.parentElement.querySelector(".campo-ob");

        if(!input.value) {
            input.classList.add("invalido");
            campoOb.innerHTML = "campo obrigatório";
            
        } else {
            input.classList.remove("invalido");
            campoOb.style.display = "block"
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Lá dentro do `forEach`, ao definir o `campoOb`, o `parentElement` de todos os seus inputs é o form. Portanto, `input.parentElement.querySelector(".campo-ob");` é a mesma coisa que um `form.querySelector(".campo-ob");`. Como o form possui diversos elementos com a classe `campoOb`, o querySelector vai retornar sempre o primeiro. Ou seja, você itera seus inputs e para cada um você seta mais uma vez o innerHtml lá do mesmo campoOb.

Comment: Teste o seguinte, acho que vai funcionar: `const campoOb = input.querySelector(":scope ~ .campo-ob");`

Comment: Isso significa que para cada input, você quer que `campoOb` seja o elemento seguinte de mesmo nível hierárquico que tenha a classe campoOb.

Comment: cara eu testei essa tua opção aqui e não retornou foi mais nada kkk, eu vou testar as outras respostas do pessoal aqui, e se der certo vou avisar

Answer (score -2):

**(** *Lamento pela resposta anterior, não considerei os inputs no formulário, minha resposta estava incompleta e longe de ser a resposta correta!* **)**

_  O empecilho esta acontecendo na utilização da mesma classe `campo-ob` para todas as spans.

Quando utilizou querySelector estará pegando apenas o primeiro elemento da classe.

```
const campoOb =
            input.parentElement.querySelector(".campo-ob");
```

Uma ideia é criar uma classe díspar para cada **span** de forma dinâmica pelo javascript e remover do html

```
<form id="form">
            <input class="input" type="text" name="Nome" id="Nome" placeholder="Nome completo*">
            <input class="input" type="text" name="E-mail" id="email" placeholder="E-mail*">
            <input class="input" type="text" name="Telefone" id="Telefone" placeholder="Telefone*">
            <textarea class="input" name="Texto" cols="30" rows="10" id="Texto"></textarea>
            <p class="campos">*campos obrigatórios</p>
            <button class="botao">Enviar</button>
          </form>
```

A função  [**insertAdjacentElement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) sera responsavel por inserir um novo elemento na posição específica,  ira adicionar um **span** após o  input ser localizado e terá a tarefa de mostrar a mensagem `campo obrigatório`, ou utilizar o [**appendChild**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) nesse caso

```
input.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", campoOb);
```

O parâmetro  *afterend* da função `insertAdjacentElement` é inerente onde um novo elemento deve ser introduzido

Para não pegar só o primeiro elemento, o [**nextElementSibling**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling) ira retornar o próximo elemento irmão.

```
const campoOb = input.nextElementSibling;
```

utilizando o :

```
let valido = true;
```

para verificar quando as entradas do formulário estiver preenchidas;

código completo :

```
const inputsFormulario = document.querySelectorAll(".input");
const form = document.getElementById("form");

inputsFormulario.forEach((input) => {
  const campoOb = document.createElement("span");
  campoOb.className = "campo-ob";
  input.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", campoOb);
});

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  let valido = true;
  inputsFormulario.forEach((input) => {
    const campoOb = input.nextElementSibling;
    if (!input.value) {
      input.classList.add("invalido");
      campoOb.textContent = "campo obrigatório";
      valido = false;
    } else {
      input.classList.remove("invalido");
      campoOb.textContent = "";
    }
  });

  if (!valido) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Dessa forma terá campos obrigatório e mostrara a mensagem abaixo de cada entrada.

Answer (score -2):

O problema do seu código está no uso da propriedade `parentElement` seguido da função `querySelector()` na atribuição do campoOb.

```
const campoOb = input.parentElement.querySelector(".campo-ob");
```

A propriedade parentElement retorna o nó `<form>` do seu HTML, após isso a função querySelector() retorna o primeiro nó encontrado dentro do `<form>` com a classe `campo-ob` e atribui seu valor a constante `campoOb`, sendo esse nó o único modifico em todos os casos de inputs vazios.

Para resolver esse problema utilize a propriedade [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling) presente no input para atribuir valor ao `campoOb`.

```
const campoOb = input.nextElementSibling;
```

Essa propriedade retornará o nó imediatamente abaixo do nó input e você poderá alterar as propriedades dele da mesma maneira que seu código atual.

Comment: Usar o nextElementSibling; funcionou perfeitamente, retornou EXATAMENTE como deveria, eu deixo aqui meu muito obrigado a todos que me ajudaram a completar esse formulário, pessoal daqui é muito gente fina, e de quebra ainda aprendi uma coisa nova.